# testing closures

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a very simple method I'm trying to test. _interactionService puts up dialog that asks the user for confirmation about deleting the customer. If the appropriate button is clicked on the box the supplied action is called. The action manipulates the context and saves changes. After the save is complete another action is called.

```
    private void Delete(object entity)
{
    _interactionService.ShowConfirmationBox("Delete?", "Are you sure you want to delete this customer?", () =>
        {
            Customer customer = entity as Customer;
            Context.Attach(customer);
            Context.Delete(customer);
            Context.Save(() => DoSomethingElseWhenSaveComplete);
        });
}
```

I'm at a loss as to how to test this method. I have mocked the service and the context, but how to test the closures?

Comment: Don't know the answer, I'm thinking about it. You shouldn't test private methods, thou.

Comment: why the `tdd` tag? there should probably be `unit-testing` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the context is mocked, then you can use a [callback](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) in your test:

```
Action saveAction = null;
contextMock
  .Setup(c => c.Save(It.IsAny<Action>())
  .Callback<Action>(a => saveAction = a);

// Call delete...

Assert.IsNotNull(saveAction);

saveAction();

// Assert that DoSomethingElseWhenSaveCompleted was done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be testing this at the service (API) level and not the UI layer.  What are you trying to achieve with your test?

1. Are you trying to confirm you can call delete

or

1. Are you trying to test the delete method

My assumption would be number 2 so write a test against the service layer versus the UI class.